# Remote debugging - Windows PDB are not supported by .NET Core debugger - how to publish correctly?

Tags: c#, .net-core, deployment

I'm writting ASP.NET Core APP in .NET Core 2.1 on Windows and after deploying it on server after using

`dotnet publish --configuration Debug -r linux-x64` I'm unable to connect via remote debugger over `SSH`

because:

`WARNING: Could not load symbols for 'Common.dll'. '/home/dev/Common.pdb' is a Windows PDB. These are not supported by the cross-platform .NET Core debugger.`

Why it does happen? and how I have to publish to be able to debug it remotely?

Comment: Project > Properties > Build tab > Advanced button > "Debugging information" setting.  Having this wrong in an asp.net.core project is pretty strange, the IDE and project templates keep you out of basic trouble like this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Only portable PDBs are supported around all platforms in .NET Core. You have to enable them in your `csproj` file

```
 <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
```

You can also check the [documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/main/accepted/2020/diagnostics/portable-pdb.md) and follow some articles, like [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/MIEngine/wiki/Offroad-Debugging-of-.NET-Core-on-Linux---OSX-from-Visual-Studio) or [this](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/RemoteDebuggingANETCoreLinuxAppInWSL2FromVisualStudioOnWindows.aspx) explaining how to setup this kind of debugging over SSH using `vsdbg`